# How to make milliseconds optional in @JsonFormat for Timestamp parsing with Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, iso8601

I have the following declaration in my object:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX")
private ZonedDateTime start;
```

And when I parse timestamps like 2016-12-08T12:16:07.124Z (using Jackson Json De-serilaizer) it works fine, but once I receive timestamps **without milliseconds** (such as "2016-12-08T12:16:07Z"), it throws exception.

How I can possibly make milliseconds optional in format specification?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you are using Java 8 Try specifying `.SSS` inside square brackets `[.SSS]`

```
JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[.SSS]X")
```

Comment: Does not work on Java 8 version 102. The brackets are also not mentioned in the JavaDoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: [.SSS] works only for a 3 digit millisecond values. if its one digit or 2 digit it breaks. E.g. 2019-03-24T16:14:08.23 will need "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[.SS] pattern

Answer (score 14):

If millis consist of 1 or 2 or 3 digit you can use this pattern

```
JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[.SSS][.SS][.S]X")
```

Optional section order strict

Answer (score 4):

For those of you that were not able to get the `[.SSS]` solution to work, here is what I ended up doing.

Retain the `@JsonFormat` annotation on your field for serialization, but build a custom deserializer for parsing Dates which might not have the milliseconds portion specified. Once you implement the deserializer you will have to register it with your `ObjectMapper` as a `SimpleModule`

```
class DateDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Date> {

    private static final SimpleDateFormat withMillis = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");
    private static final SimpleDateFormat withoutMillis = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX");

    public DateDeserializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public DateDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        String dateString = p.getText();
        if (dateString.isEmpty()) {
            //handle empty strings however you want,
            //but I am setting the Date objects null
            return null;
        }

        try {
            return withMillis.parse(dateString);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            try {
                return withoutMillis.parse(dateString);
            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Unable to parse date", e1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now that you have a custom deserializer, all that is left is to register it. I am doing so with a `ContextResolver<ObjectMapper>` that I already had in my project, but however you work with your `ObjectMapper` should be fine.

```
@Provider
class ObjectMapperContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    public ObjectMapperContextResolver() {
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SimpleModule dateModule = new SimpleModule();
        dateModule.addDeserializer(Date.class, new DateDeserializer());
        mapper.registerModule(dateModule);
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

Comment: Very useful information on how to register a custom ObjectMapper in a JEE application.