# How to make seconds optional for Jackson @JsonFormat?

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41037243/how-to-make-milliseconds-optional-in-jsonformat-for-timestamp-parsing-with-jack) I read that one can specify the pattern attribute of @JsonFormat so that a specific part of the date or time is optional. I would like the seconds of a time to be optional. So that values like "22:10" and "22:10:00" would be parsed. I had a look at the documentation and figured that the "s" is the correct [pattern letter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendPattern-java.lang.String-) for seconds.

```
@JsonProperty
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "HH:mm[.ss]")
private LocalTime test5;
```

I thought that if I put two "s" in square brackets and prepend them with a dot things should work. However, only the value "22:10" is accepted. If I pass a value like "22:10:00" I am getting the following error:

```
Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalTime` from String "22:10:00": Text '22:10:00' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 5
```

How can I make the seconds optional using only the annotation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "HH:mm[.ss]")
```

In this line, the format you are using for seconds is `'.ss'`.
If the seconds will have ':' in front then you need to use this pattern: `"HH:mm[:ss]"`