# Jackson date pattern for deserialization microseconds/milliseconds

Tags: java, jackson, date-format

I receive messages from a service, a message contains date. Date can come in two formats:
2022-03-11T22:45:54.448907 - 6 digits after dot (kind of microseconds), and 2022-03-11T22:45:54.448 - three digits after dot (plain millis). I'm using java and jackson to deserialize the response. Is there a way to keep things simple like in the snippet below? Or I have to write a custom deserializer?

```
@Data
class A {

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")
    private Date dateTime;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make milliseconds optional in @JsonFormat for Timestamp parsing with Jackson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41037243/how-to-make-milliseconds-optional-in-jsonformat-for-timestamp-parsing-with-jack)